# Excel vlookup fails to match the same text while value comparison (cell A2 = Cell B2) works

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following text in an excel cell.
If i copy it to another column and compare the 2 cells it returns 'TRUE'
but if I vlookup the same value from one column to another it returns a '#VALUE' error

text provided below

> AL1715V04','AL1715V05','AL1725A08','AL1725V01','AL1725V03','AL1725V04','AL1731V03','AL1738V08','AL1738V09','AL1746V09','AL1801V04','AL1817V09','AL1824V01','AL1824V02','AL1824V03','AL1824V04','AL1824V05','AL1824V06','AL1833V01','AL1833V02','AL1833V03','AL1833V04','AL1833V05','AL1833V06','AL1834V01','AL1834V02','AL1834V03','AL1834V04','AL1834V05','AL1834V06','WEBS&STEST6/12','AL1724V09','AL1724V11','AL1737V02','AL1737V03','AL1737V04','AL1737V05'ZOETIS

Comment: It appears that `VLOOKUP` is limited to having the lookup string (first argument) be 255 characters or less. Yours is more than 255 characters. See, for example, [vLookup Character Limit Error - Excel 2010](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/vlookup-character-limit-error-excel-2010/1212bfb7-de44-4856-aba6-4c90ec90c7ed?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

You are either omitting VLOOKUP's fourth argument or using True.

Both True or no value (True by default when omitted) requires **data sorted in an ascending order**. Your data is not sorted.

Use False as the optional fourth argument.

Since you decided it wasn't important to include your formula, you should be able to make the addition yourself.

Comment: You assume much...even with the last argument `False` it doesn't work; but the OP should still include the formula.

Comment: Looks like I provided an inadequate answer for an inadequate question.

Comment: thanks for the reposnes, i had the 4th argument set to true, sorry for not posting the vlookup formula, but if you use the text provided and try it out in excel with the 4th argument as TRUE it still doesn't work. 
I found the solution (using INDEX and MATCH), will post it as the answer.. apparently it has something to do with array formulas

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...it appears that `VLookup` has a limit of 255 characters after which it will return `#VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum string size VLOOKUP (or MATCH) can compare is 255 characters. Since your string has 453 characters the lookup fails.

Answer (score 0):

Will try to post the reference link where I found the answer, the #VALUE error was most probably due to 255 character limit, or carriage returns in the text.
the below formula resolved my issue:

(this is an array formula, so you have to press Ctl+shift+enter after typing in the formula in the cell.
replace the text in Bold with your reference lookup array and value)

{=MATCH(TRUE, **LookupArray** = **LookupValue**,0)}